# Synchronous call in UI5 v2 ODataModel

Tags: xmlhttprequest, sapui5

I have a service the I am loading from the `Component.js` file that calls the backend ABAP system and returns application configuration options for a UI5 application.

The issue I am running into is I really need this call to be a synchronous blocking call as it contains some application control items that is used by the UI to control some of the available functionality.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to make the read operation synchronous?

Comment: Why isn't it possible to trigger the UI later in the success callback? Have you tried solving the issue with a promise? Would be nice if we could see some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

> You can do this odata by setting the property **async:false**

See the documentation below:
[image]

The default value is true i.e async. You can set it to false and block the UI until response is received.

Comment: This applies only to the old `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel` which is deprecated. Future ODataModels don't allow synch XHRs and I hope they keep it that way.